# Calculating values related to angular momentum and then their uncertainties

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum

Here is the problem:

[image]

And here is my work (sorry it is handwritten, it would take a while to type this out)

[image]

[image]

My problem is that I'm not sure if it's right or if it makes sense to keep getting 0 for the uncertainties. Is there some intuitive reason why this makes sense in this context? Also could I have gone about this question by calculating the commutators, for part b) [H, $l^2$], for part c) [$l^2, l_z$], [$l^2, l_y$], and [$l^2, l_x$], and then for part d) [$l_z, l^2 $], all of which equal 0 (and because the commutators equal 0, the uncertainty is 0)?

Comment: But it also takes a while for us to read the dark picture with hand right and decipher what was the line of your thought in the formulas you indicate. In short, what you think that it is the Hamiltonian of your particle? And, by the way, I hope that the momentum of inertia $I$ is an integer or half-integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My problem is that I'm not sure if it's right or if it makes sense to
>   keep getting 0 for the uncertainties. Is there some intuitive reason
>   why this makes sense in this context?

Yes, it is right. Your $Y_{lm}$ are eigenfunctions of all the operators for which you are calculating the uncertainties. So the uncertainty is necessarily zero!

If 
$$
\hat O |\psi>=\lambda |\psi>
$$
then
$$
\hat O^2|\psi>=\lambda^2|\psi>
$$
and so
$$
<\hat O^2>=<\hat O>^2=\lambda^2
$$

...and so
$$
<\hat O^2>-<\hat O>^2=0
$$